# Firebase and stack nav both cant export in app.js at the same time

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, react-navigation

I have a Stack Navigator and some firebase functions in my app.js file. After implementing the Stack I am unable to use the log out button in the listScreen component because I found I cant export multiple in app.js. If I remove one export for app.js for example the Stack will work and vice versa.

App.js problem

```
//export navigation, container to wrap root navigator 
export default createAppContainer(Switcher);

//PROBLEM cant have multiple exports, ether the Switcher or App class can export Individually 

//class for app
 export default class App extends Component {
```

Here is all the code in app.js

```
//Blue List is has been created by Ameer Yasin and Nick

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';
//firebase 
import firebase from './servers/firebase.js';
//navigation 
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';

//components and sub component 
import Login from './components/LoginPage.js';
import { SpinLoad } from './components/common/index.js';
import ListScreen from './components/ListScreen';
import AboutScreen from './components/AboutScreen';

// switch stack navigator 
const Switcher = createStackNavigator(
  {
    //from listScreen to about screen 
    TaskPg: ListScreen,
    AboutPg: AboutScreen
  },
  {
    //the route of nav
    initialRouteName: "TaskPg",
    //header title 
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      title: 'BlueList'
    }
  }
)
//export navigation, container to wrap root navigator 
export default createAppContainer(Switcher);

//PROBLEM cant have multiple exports, ether the Switcher or App class can export Individually 

//class for app
 export default class App extends Component {
  //are u logged in set state to null 
  state = { loggedIn: null };

  componentWillMount() {

    //when logged in call this function
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      //logged in  
      if (user) {
        this.setState({ loggedIn: true });
      } //logged out 
      else {
        this.setState({ loggedIn: false });
      }
    });
  }

  renderContent() {
    //render content depending on auth status 
    switch (this.state.loggedIn) {
      //goto list screen when logged in 
      case true: return (
        <ListScreen />
      )

      //if not logged in goto log in page 
      case false: return <Login />;

      //show loading icon by default 
      default: return <SpinLoad size='large' />
    }
  }

  //render content on screen 
  render() {
    return (
      //SafeAreaView container for content 
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        {this.renderContent()}

      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
};

//styles
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Here is the list screen where the Stack Navigator is. Again, the navigator works only if I remove the export for App in app.js therefore the sigh out wont work... I need both to work.

```
const ListScreen = props => {


    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>

            {/* add task component with date picker */}
            <AddItemModel />

            {/* button pressed to goto About Screen */}
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('AboutPg')}>
                    <Text style={styles.aboutBtn}>About App</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>

            {/* sign out button linked to firebase log out */}
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => firebase.auth().signOut()} >
                <Text style={styles.button} >Sign Out</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>

        </View>
    );

}
```

I would really appreciate some help, I tried many methods for multiple exports as well as moving the firebase login functions in another component and still had the same issue.

**UPDATE**
Here is what was suggested, I tried to add the import statement with the correct path and it wont work.

```
import React from 'react';
import firebase from '../servers/firebase';
import { Text, StyleSheet, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import AddItemModel from './common/AddItemModel';

//what was suggested
import {default as AppNavigator, App} from "../App"


const ListScreen = props => {

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>

            {/* add task component with date picker */}
            <AddItemModel />

            {/* button pressed to goto About Screen */}
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('AboutPg')}>
                    <Text style={styles.aboutBtn}>About App</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>

            {/* sign out button linked to firebase log out */}
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => firebase.auth().signOut()} >
                <Text style={styles.button} >Sign Out</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>

        </View>
    );

}
```

File directory structure screenshot. The two relivent files are App.js and ListScreen.js

[image]

Comment: You can have multiple exports, you just can't have multiple ***default*** exports.  Try `import {default as AppNavigator, App} from "app.js"`.

Comment: That did not work, got an error. Im trying to export and not import.

Comment: Remove the `default` from `class App`.  Like I said, you can't have more than 1 default export.

Comment: Could you update your post with the directory structure for the relevant files please? Would help with understanding the problem. The solution suggested should be sufficient in a normal setup.

Comment: Updated with file structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can absolutely have multiple exports, you just can't have multiple ***default*** exports.  Try `import {default as AppNavigator, App} from "app.js"`.

So something like:

```js
// app.js
export default createAppContainer(Switcher);
export class App extends Component {}

// component.js
import {default as AppNavigator, App} from "app.js"

const MyComponent = () => (
  <div>
    <AppNavigator/>
    <App/>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Tried that and got this error: Unable to resolve "app.js" from "components/ListScreen.js"
Failed building JavaScript bundle.

Comment: How are you trying to import things in your component file in your working example?  Add that import statement to you question.  The `"app.js"` in my example probably isn't at the correct path for you.  It's probably something like `../app.js`.

Comment: The component is a child of app.js. I did not need to import the Stack Navigator or the app.js into the component for it to work. However if I have more then one export in app.js one of both fails fails to work. I added the component code for you.